# copy a linked list with next and random pointer, only read privileges are given on list

Tags: algorithm, list, data-structures

I need to copy a linked list with next and random pointer.The next pointer as usual points to the next element in the linked list and the random pointer might point to any of the other node or even on itself.
How can this be done if I am not allowed to modify the given list at any time, only read privileges are given on the list.

Comment: Either I am missing something, or your description of the problem is missing something. Surely if you have read access to the original list and next pointers, you just start at the list head, copy that node and follow the next pointer - done?

Comment: @us2012 I think you are expected to properly initialize those "random" pointers so they point to the nodes of the new list and not the nodes of the original list. So, it's not a full node copy, you need to change two pointers in every node.

Comment: @Alexey Ah! Yeah, that makes more sense.

Comment: the solution requires O(n) solution where n is the no of nodes in the list.

Comment: the pointers both the next and the random pointer can't be changed in the original list

Answer (score 16):

Elegant solution (linear time, constant space):

Create copies of Node 1, 2, 3...n and insert them between 1 and 2, 2 and 3 and so on, ignoring the `random` field for now. So there are 2n nodes total in the list.

Now set the value of `random` fields in the new nodes in the following way with a single pass:

```
original.next.random = original.random.next
```

This works, because LHS is the `random` field in the newly created node, and RHS is the pointer to the arbitrary's node's copy, exactly what we wanted.

Now restore the original linked list in a single pass, and return the new list.

```
original.next = original.next.next;
copy.next = copy.next.next;
```

The solution is taken from [here.](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=14417753)

Comment: What about the restriction that the original list be read-only?

Answer (score 13):

The simplest solution would be something like this...

You traverse the original linked list and create another linked list, whose nodes are the same as in the original list, with proper `next` pointers, pointing to the corresponding nodes of the new list. You keep the `random` pointers as they are for now.

While you're traversing the list you also put the old list's node address/pointer and the new list's node address/pointer onto an `associative array` (AKA map, hash table, etc), where the old list's node address/pointer is the `key` and the new list's node address/pointer is the `value`.

Then you traverse the new list and replace the `random` pointer in every node with the `value` from the associative array corresponding to the `key` equal to the `random` pointer.

A hash table can be used as an associative array to achieve time and memory cost proportional to the number of elements in the original list.

The time & space complexity of this solution is O(n) each.

Comment: Yep, nice. Would be interesting to see whether there is a solution where the `O(n)` is strict rather than amortized!

Comment: +1 . Once in an interview with microsoft i gave the same answer as that of @Max (inserting nodes between the old nodes then ....... ). But they explicitly asked me to solve the question using HashMap. Exact solution given by Alexey Frunze was expected. Somehow i arrived to the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct node * copy(struct node * head) 
{
   struct node *dummy;
   struct node *dummy1=dummy;
   struct node *head1=head;

   struct node *map[1000000];
   while(head) {
      dummy->next=new struct node;
      map[head]=dummy->next;
      dummy->next->data=head->data;
      dummy=dummy->next;
      head=head->next
   }
   dummy=dummy1;
   head=head1;
   while(head){
      dummy->next->arb=map[head->arb];
      dummy=dummy->next;
      head=head->next;
   }
   return dummy1->next;
}
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. you may want to add some explanations as to why and how your answer works. (be it in text or code comments). so the OP can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct node_s{
int data;
struct node_s *next;
struct node_s *arbit;
} Node_s;

void free_list(Node_s * head){
if(!head) return;
Node_s * temp = head;
Node_s * next = head;
while(temp){
    next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    temp = next;
}
}
void push_1(Node_s **head, int value){
if(*head == NULL){
    (*head) = (Node_s *)malloc(sizeof(Node_s));
    (*head)->data = value;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
}
else{
    Node_s * temp = (Node_s *)malloc(sizeof(Node_s));
    if(temp){
        temp->data = value;
        temp->next = (*head);
        *head = temp;
    }
}
}
void add_arbit(Node_s *L1, int a, int b){
 Node_s * first = L1;
 Node_s * second = L1;

 while(first){
     if(first->data == a)
         break;
     first = first->next;
 }
 while(second){
    if(second->data == b)
        break;
    second = second->next;
}
if(first)
    first->arbit = second;
}
Node_s * create_node(int val){

Node_s * temp =  (Node_s *)malloc(sizeof(Node_s));
if(temp){
    temp->data = val;
    temp->next = NULL;
}
return temp;
}

Node_s * clone(Node_s * node){

if(!node) return NULL;
Node_s * current = node;

//First insert clone nodes in original linked list.     
while(current){
    Node_s * current_next = current->next;
    current->next  =  create_node(current->data);
    current->next->next = current_next;
    current = current_next;
}
current = node;

//Now copy arbit pointer of each node to cloned list
Node_s * clone_head  = current->next;
while(current){
    Node_s * clone = current->next;
    if(current->arbit){
        clone->arbit    = current->arbit->next;
    }
    current = clone->next;
}

current = node;

//Segregate two linked list
while(current){
    Node_s * clone  = current->next;
    current->next = clone->next;
    if(clone->next){
        clone->next = clone->next->next;
    }
    current = current->next;
}
//return head pointer to the calling function
return clone_head;
}

int main(){
Node_s * L1 = NULL;
push_1(&L1,1);
push_1(&L1,2);
push_1(&L1,3);
push_1(&L1,4);
push_1(&L1,5);
push_1(&L1,6);

add_arbit(L1,1,6);
add_arbit(L1,2,5);
add_arbit(L1,3,1);
add_arbit(L1,4,2);
add_arbit(L1,5,4);
add_arbit(L1,6,3);

print_list_1(L1);

Node_s *clone_head  = clone(L1);
free_list(L1);
print_list_1(clone_head);

return 0;    
}
```

Comment: This code is quite involved and having no commentary with this code is not justified.  Please leave some comments or explanation as to how this code works, and how you justified the design choices you made to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recursion solution (in java):

```
public class Solution {  

    public HashMap<RandomListNode, RandomListNode> createdNode;   
    public RandomListNode copyRandomList(RandomListNode head) {  
        createdNode = new HashMap<RandomListNode, RandomListNode>();  
        return cc(head);  
    }  

    private RandomListNode cc(RandomListNode node) {  
        if(node == null)  
        {  
            return null;  
        }  

        RandomListNode newNode = new RandomListNode(node.label);  

        createdNode.put(node, newNode);          
        newNode.next = cc(node.next);  

        //now assign the random pointer  
        RandomListNode newRandom = null;  
        if(node.random != null)  
        {  
            newRandom = createdNode.get(node.random);  
        }  
        newNode.random = newRandom;  

        return newNode;      
    }  
}
```

And here is the solution using HashMap (also in java):

```
public class Solution{  

    public RandomListNode copyRandomList(RandomListNode head) {  
        if(head == null) return null;  
        java.util.HashMap<RandomListNode, RandomListNode> map = new java.util.HashMap<RandomListNode, RandomListNode>();  
        RandomListNode copiedHead = new RandomListNode(head.label);  
        map.put(head, copiedHead);  

        for(RandomListNode cur = head.next, cpLst = copiedHead; cur != null; cur = cur.next, cpLst = cpLst.next){  
            cpLst.next = new RandomListNode(cur.label);  
            map.put(cur, cpLst.next);  
        }  
        for(RandomListNode cur = head, cpCur = copiedHead; cur != null; cur = cur.next, cpCur = cpCur.next)  
            cpCur.random = cur.random == null ? null : map.get(cur.random);  
        return copiedHead;  
    }  
}
```

The other approach without read-only requirement is possible [here.](http://traceformula.blogspot.com/2015/07/copy-list-with-random-pointers.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Start from head node and create a copy of Node one by one
2. When you create a copy make entry of original node and Copy node in hash map as key, value.
3. make a new list as we copy element one by one, so we got a next pointer value for every node.
   4.then traverse original list again with new list to copy random pointer. we can get random pointer for respective node in hash map.

For detailed explanation visit: http://www.dscoding.com/2016/10/copy-linked-list-with-random-pointer.html